# Footnote index size and position

Tags: xetex, footnotes, lengths

Is there a way to drop the footnote index below?
I looked away https://www.ctan.org/pkg/footmisc
But I didn't find anything there to help me

`\hangfootparskip \hangfootparindent \footnotemargin`

```
\documentclass[twoside, 14pt, openright]{extreport}
\usepackage[a5paper, outer=15mm,inner=12mm,top=20mm,bottom=15mm,footskip=1em,headsep=4pt,headheight=1em]{geometry}
% \usepackage[a5paper, outer=36mm,inner=15mm,top=20mm,bottom=28mm,footskip=1.5em,headsep=4pt,headheight=1em]{geometry}
\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}    %% загружает пакет многоязыковой вёрстки
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}
\usepackage{metalogo}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[verbose]{microtype}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\def\sectiontitlename{РОЗДІЛ}
\def\parttitlename{Частина}

\author{Ігор Юхименко}
% =============================================================================
%
%                           НАЛАШТОВУЄМО ШРИФТИ
%
% =============================================================================
%\DeclareMicrotypeAlias{Kraskario}{TU-basic}
\DeclareMicrotypeAlias{Kraskario}{TU-basic}

\setstretch {0.85}
\setmainfont{Kraskario}         
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}

\begin{document}

\counterwithin*{footnote}{part}
\newcommand{\speek}{—\enspace}

Lorem lipsum\footnote{dollor amet si} defunden gilroy next words lang.

\end{document}
```

Footnotemark is very Up from text line (for this font only)

[image]

Comment: You could redefine \footnotemark to not use \textsuperscript.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, this takes no effect \renewcommand{\footnotemark}{\thefootnote}

Comment: It's likely that we will need to know what document class you're using to be able to answer this.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, I made so \deffootnotemark{\raisebox{0.3em}{\hspace*{0.4pt}\scriptsize{\thefootnotemark}}\hspace*{0.4pt}} with KOMAscript

Comment: You have not provided an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows what you have done and what the problem is. Please help us.

Comment: @PeterWilson, I'm edit question

Comment: See sourc2e.pdf from ctan (you probably already have a copy, if you can find it) for the definiton of \footnotemark.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, I don't quite understand what file it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it was `\@makefnmark` that needed to be modified.

However, I am still getting errors w.r.t. the font selection.

```
\documentclass[twoside, 14pt, openright]{extreport}
\usepackage[a5paper, outer=15mm,inner=12mm,top=20mm,bottom=15mm,footskip=1em,headsep=4pt,headheight=1em]{geometry}
% \usepackage[a5paper, outer=36mm,inner=15mm,top=20mm,bottom=28mm,footskip=1.5em,headsep=4pt,headheight=1em]{geometry}
\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}    %% загружает пакет многоязыковой вёрстки
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}
\usepackage{metalogo}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[verbose]{microtype}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\def\sectiontitlename{РОЗДІЛ}
\def\parttitlename{Частина}

\makeatletter
\def\@makefnmark{\hbox{\@textsubscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}
\makeatother

\author{Ігор Юхименко}
% =============================================================================
%
%                           НАЛАШТОВУЄМО ШРИФТИ
%
% =============================================================================
%\DeclareMicrotypeAlias{Kraskario}{TU-basic}
\DeclareMicrotypeAlias{Kraskario}{TU-basic}

\setstretch {0.85}
\setmainfont{Kraskario}         
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}

\begin{document}

\counterwithin*{footnote}{part}
\newcommand{\speek}{—\enspace}

Lorem lipsum\footnote{dollor amet si} defunden gilroy next words lang.

\end{document}
```